# Changing part of view at runtime

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I show several movie items in an ObservableCollection using a typical listbox+datatemplate view. 
However, I want, in the same page, to be able to quickly change the view to what I define a posterview (i.e. only the posterimages in a wrappanel).

The xaml-page uses a viewmodel as datacontext.

Is there a way to basically replace part of the XAML content with another?
And still keep as little code as possible in the codebehind of the view.

I've seen WPF examples that for example use a DataTrigger bound to a viewmodelproperty which is very clean,
such as [this article](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/)
... but Windows Phone does not have a DataTriggers, correct?

I'm trying to go for an MVVM-ish approach, so as little code as possible in the view code-behind is required.

So I want to change this:

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding CinemaShowsOverview }" Template="{StaticResource ListView}" />
```

To:

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding CinemaShowsOverview }" Template="{StaticResource PosterView}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataTemplates with a DataTemplateSelector would be the way to go around this problem.

Base Data Template Selector:

```
public class DataTemplateSelector : ContentControl
{
    public virtual DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

        ContentTemplate = SelectTemplate(newContent, this);
    }
}
```

Specialized Template Selector for your `CinemaShowsOverview`

```
public class CinemaShowsTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ListTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DataTemplate PosterTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return DefaultTemplate;

        var viewModel = item as CinemaShowsOverview;
        if (viewModel != null)
            return viewModel.IsPoster ? PowerTemplate : ListTemplate;
        else
            return DefaultTemplate;
    }
}
```

And then in XAML (replacing your current `ContentControl`):

```
<assets:CinemaShowsTemplateSelector PosterTemplate="{StaticResource PosterView}"
                                    ListTemplate="{StaticResource ListView}"
                                    Content="{Binding CinemaShowsOverview}">
```

Comment: Maybe DataTemplateSelector should be an abstract class and SelectTemplate should be abstract?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be pedantic, the blog you mention describes typed data-templates, not datatriggers (as the author class them). No, this feature is not available in Silverlight for WP7.

You could expose the template you requires as a string within your view model, i.e. a string that is either `ListView` or `PosterView`. You then bind your `Template` property to this view-model property via a value converter that provides the template, which it can access via your applications `Resources`.

Comment: PS The second part of the blog uses DataTriggers though :)

Comment: Actually DataTemplates a really good idea. See my answer for how to utilize them.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen you're right. +1 to your answer from me. A bit simpler than a value converter.